# Edit user registration form xml

Tags: css, xml, joomla2.5

Change name to business name in user registration form. It is a cosmetic change.
Please advise xml

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using GB English, I believe the labels that you want to change are in file `language\en-GB\en-GB.com_users.ini` at/around line 64

```
COM_USERS_PROFILE_NAME_DESC="Enter your full name"
COM_USERS_PROFILE_NAME_LABEL="Name:"
```